# XP client losing its connection to the SBS domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs-2003

I have a XP SP3 PRO Client connecting to an SBS 2003 server. The client keeps losing connection to the network, printers etc.

The machine is in Active Directory  but didn't have an A record or PTR record in DNS. I have added these manually.

The event log contained the following errors:

**Error 1**

> The system failed to register host (A) resource records (RRs) for
>   network adapter with settings:
>
> The reason the system could not register these RRs was because the DNS
>   server contacted refused the update request. The reasons for this
>   might be (a) you are not allowed to update the specified DNS domain
>   name, or (b) because the DNS server authoritative for this name does
>   not support the DNS dynamic update protocol.
>
> To register the DNS host (A) resource records using the specific DNS
>   domain name and IP addresses for this adapter, contact your DNS server
>   or network systems administrator.

**Error 2**

> The time provider NtpClient was unable to find a domain controller to
>   use as a time source. NtpClient will try again in 30 minutes.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

**Error 3**

> The time provider NtpClient is configured to acquire time from one or
>   more time sources, however none of the sources are currently
>   accessible.  No attempt to contact a source will be made for 29
>   minutes. NtpClient has no source of accurate time.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Does anyone know the cause of these malfunctions?

Comment: Does your SBS03 contain 1 or 2 NICs? Do you use ISA? What si your NIC(s) config (ipconfig /all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the client might be configured with the wrong DNS servers. Make sure the client is configured to use **ONLY** the SBS server for DNS.

For external name resolution, you can configure the SBS server to use forwarders or root hints. All internal clients (including the server) should use the server **ONLY** for DNS.

Comment: I wasn't able to check the clients DNS settings because I can't run the network connections as a domain admin, is there any other way to change the dns server configs?